# MySQL foreign key choosing more than one option

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a short question related to mysql but associated more with thinking than coding.

I have a table called "*EMPLOYEES*", containing fields *"id", "name*" and "**job_id**". 
In the another table called "*JOB_IDs*" I've got fields "**id**" and "description" (rest doesn't matter for now).

For the field "**job_id**" in EMPLOYEES, I've created a **foreign key to field "id"** in *JOB_IDs*.
 It works fine - when adding an employee, I can select **job id** from the list from table *JOB_IDs*.

The issue is that I would like to assign **not one** job_id for every employee, but for example **two... (or more).**

...And so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, than just adding fileds "job_id-1" "job_id-2" "job_id-3".

---

Thanks in advance for and help... and sorry for poor language - I'm just learning eng as well as web deving

Comment: Are your descriptions in your jobs table unique? or can they be repeating? For instance, do you have a job_id that is engineer and it applies to multiple employees?

Comment: you can insert emplyees that way. For selection, you can group by name (hopefully the names are unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third table with the relations

---

table EMPLOYEES:

```
columns: "id", "name".
```

table JOB_IDs:

```
columns: "id", "description".
```

table EMPLOYEES_JOB_IDs

```
columns: "id", "id_employee", "id_job_ids".
```

---

It shouldn't make to complicated your selects with JOIN

Comment: Simple and correct. @Marox44, please don't add extra fields to your employee table.  This will denormalize it and create a lot more headaches for you.